# SQL Server comparison predicate on a composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, let's say I have a table `Mytable` with a composite primary key `[ColA, ColB, ColC]`. 
I would like to do the following pseudo-query:

```
select * from Mytable where (ColA,ColB,ColC) > (SomeValA,SomeValB,SomeValC)
```

Is this possible somehow?

EDIT:
Example:

```
create table Mytable (a integer, b integer, c integer);
insert into Mytable values (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1);
```

Doing `select * from Mytable where (a,b,c) > (1,1,2)` should return rows (1,2,1) and (2,1,1)

EDIT 2: Let me rephrase:
If a total order function can be defined on an ordered subset of the columns of a table then is there a way I can query the table using this order function as a predicate?

Comment: In short: no. That query doesn't make sense. `>` requires **scalar** values on both sides.

Comment: @Larnu so how does this key gets sorted when i do order by ColA, ColB,ColC ?

Comment: By `ColA` first, then `ColB` and then (finally) `ColC`, and in all cases in `ASCENDING` order, as a direction has been omitted.

Comment: so, isnt there an implicit ordering of the whole tuple, so that  ">" does make sense  ?

Comment: Tables have no implicit order, no.

Comment: Would you please give data types and some sample data to make a suggestion.

Comment: I do not mean that tables have implicit order. I mean that a strict order function can by defined on the tuple , or else it wouldnt be possible to order by this tuple.

Comment: It's not `ORDER BY (ColA, ColB, ColC)` @Paralife . `ORDER BY YT.ColA, YT.ColB, YT.ColC;` doesn't contain any tuples.

Comment: @Larnu that's a syntactic difference, ORDER BY YT.ColA, YT.ColB, YT.ColC contains the ordered column subset [YT.ColA, YT.ColB, YT.ColC] of the table. I named it a tuple. It doesnt matter how I name it though. Also "ordered" here means the order of appearence of the columns in the subset.

Comment: You can't order by tuples, @Paralife ... I've been very clear about that in all my comments.

Comment: I explained: Forget the word "tuples". You order by an ordered subset that has defined an order function on it. This is what you do when you do ORDER BY A,B,C. There is an order function on this "thing" you dont like being named a "tuple".

Comment: `ORDER BY ColA, ColB, ColC` is nothing alike to `(ColA,ColB,ColC) > (SomeValA,SomeValB,SomeValC)` @Paralife .... I have already explained that.

Comment: I essentially asked if the order function that ORDER BY uses when you do ORDER BY ColA,ColB,ColC can be used in a query without redefining it in the query like you did in your answer. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* this is what you are after:

```
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ColA int,
                            ColB int,
                            ColC int);

--Sample Data    
WITH N AS
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES (1),
                  (2),
                  (3),
                  (4),
                  (5),
                  (6),
                  (7),
                  (8),
                  (9),
                  (10)) N (N) )
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ColA,
                           ColB,
                           ColC)
SELECT N1.N,
       N2.N,
       N3.N
FROM N N1,
     N N2,
     N N3;
GO

--Solution
DECLARE @I1 int,
        @I2 int,
        @I3 int;
SET @I1 = 5;
SET @I2 = 7;
SET @I3 = 2;


SELECT YT.ColA,
       YT.ColB,
       YT.ColC
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.ColA > @I1
   OR (YT.ColA = @I1 AND YT.ColB > @I2)
   OR (YT.ColA = @I1 AND YT.ColB = @I2 AND YT.ColC > @I3)
ORDER BY YT.ColA,
         YT.ColB,
         YT.ColC;

GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Otherwise, to repoeat my comment: *"In short: no. `>` requires scalar values on both sides."* Syntax such as `(ColA, ColB, ColC) > (@I1, @I2, @I3)` is not value. SQL does not order in tuples; this includes in the `ORDER BY`. Syntax such as `ORDER BY (ColA, ColB, ColC), OtherColumn` would also error.

Comment: I am sorry if my question isnt obvious. This is what i want indeed, but I asked because this is what I wanted to avoid, since in my case the columns are 5, so the query gets ugly and there are a considerable amount of places I need to do this query. I also dont control the Database to be able to change anything on the data definitions.

Comment: Then my answer is my first comment, @Paralife : *"
In short: no. That query doesn't make sense. `>` requires scalar values on both sides. "* You have your answer there/

Comment: I get the "no" part. thank you for that. What I disagree with is the "doesn't make sense part". Postgres has it. My original query works exactly as written in postgres. But anyway, ithe discussion is not useful any more. Thanks for the answer, honestly

Comment: It doesn't make sense, @Paralife , because `(ColA, ColB, ColC)` is not a scalar value, and in T-SQL `>` requires scalar values on **both** sides of the expression. SQL Server isn't PostgreSQL, and you cannot expect the 2 applications to behave the same or that SQL written to PostgreSQL will work in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, thats why I said "pseudo-query" in my question, but what you dont understand is that I didnt ask for literally to use ">" symbol. I am sure you know multi-dimensional sets can and do have order functions defined on them. So T-SQL doesnt provide a way to do what I want. I get this. It doesnt mean what i ask makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest would be doing math. ie:

```
select * 
from myTable
where (a * 100) + (b * 10) + c > 112;
```

Comment: Yeah , but this is an example, In the real case the data types are not all integers. there are varchars in there

Comment: Then query your design. Probably you would end up creating a function for comparison (likely CLR UDF).

Comment: It's not my design unfortunately. I was tasked to fetch some records from an SQL server database that I dont control, and I only have read permission on that table. Anyway thanks. I will propably look into the UDF solution and kindly ask them to let me define it if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use indexes, then you might need:

```
select *
from Mytable 
where a > 1 
union all
select *
from Mytable 
where a = 1 and b > 1 
union all
select *
from Mytable 
where a = 1 and b = 1 and c > 2;
```

You could also add a persisted computed column and an index:

```
alter table MyTable add abc
    concat(format(a, '00000'), ':', format(b, '00000'), ':', format(c, '00000')) persisted;

create index idx_mytable_abc as mytable(abc);
```

Then the comparison would look like:

```
where abc > '00001:00001:00002'
```

and this can use the index.